# Will Bartender 7.75 work with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I have bartender 7.75 on Windows 7.

It works, except when I try to print the barcode, it won't print.

In Windows XP it prints fine.

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked to whoever is making Bartender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BarTender 7.5 is from 2006/2007, and barely supports Vista in that version (7.75 SP2).

My guess would be that you need to ensure you have a correct/updated printer driver for Windows 7.

The people who make BarTender offer updated printer drivers [here](http://www.seagullscientific.com/aspx/thermal_95.aspx) but I'm not sure if they work with anything older than version 9.x.

Here's the company's contact info (Seagull Scientific) [here](http://www.seagullscientific.com/aspx/contact_us.aspx) if you need some help; Also, they're currently having an upgrade promotion until the end of Aug. 2010 for people who are running older 7.x versions.

Hope the helps...